# Deadlock with custom ThreadsafeCollection class

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I know, how ironic that I'm having more trouble with deadlocks while implementing this `ThreadsafeCollection` class than I would have had otherwise... in any case:

I'm trying to create a simple collection class that maintains its own thread synchronization for adds, removes, and iterations. Everything seems to work well, except iterating over the collection via `foreach` or Linq. It uses a private `ReaderWriterLockSlim` which calls `EnterWriteLock()/ExitWriteLock()` in the `Add()` and `Remove()` methods, and returns a `SafeEnumerator<T>` in the call to `GetEnumerator()`. The `SafeEnumerator<T>` implements `IEnumerator<T>` and receives a reference to the aforementioned `ReaderWriterLockSlim` via it's constructor so that it may call `EnterReadLock()` during construction, and `ExitReadLock()` in `Dispose()`.

The problem I'm noticing (by experiencing deadlocks and verifying that `ExitReadLock()` (and therefore `SafeEnumerator.Dispose()`)is not being called) is that the collection is sometimes unable to acquire writelocks, because one or more threads do not release their readlocks (through the safe enumerator). This is despite the fact that my `ReaderWRiterLockSlim` is constructed with the `LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion` property.

The only places in my code that iterate over the `ThreadsafeCollection` do so with either a `foreach` or a LINQ expression, and it was my understanding that obtaining the (safe)enumerator this way does not require an explicit call to `Dispose()`, even in the case of an exception during iteration.

My question is: Am I misunderstanding something about the way foreach/LINQ/dispose work together? For what reason could a thread fail to call `SafeEnumerator.Dispose()`, given that the thread only obtains the enumerator through foreach or LINQ?

For reference, I've posted the relevant portions of my `ThreadsafeCollection` and `SafeEnumerator` below.

Thanks for your help!

**ThreadsafeCollection:**

```cs
public class ThreadsafeCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  private ICollection<T> _collection;
  private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);

  public ThreadsafeCollection()
  {
    _collection = new Collection<T>();    
  }

  public void Add(T item)
  {
    _lock.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
      _collection.Add(item);
    }

    finally
    {
      _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }

  public bool Remove(T item)
  {
    _lock.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
      return _collection.Remove(item);
    }
    finally
    {
      _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return new SafeEnumerator<T>(_collection.GetEnumerator(), _lock);
  }
}
```

**SafeEnumerator:**

```cs
public class SafeEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
  {
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;

    public SafeEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner, ReaderWriterLockSlim collectionlock)
    {
      _inner = inner;
      _lock = collectionlock;
      _lock.EnterReadLock();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
      return _inner.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
      _inner.Reset();
    }

    public T Current
    {
      get { return _inner.Current; }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
      get { return Current; }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you verified that your enumerations are always enumerating to the end? If they stop in the middle (or have a write operation occur in the middle on the same thread as the enumeration) then that would be an easy way to deadlock. One way to avoid this would be to return an enumerator that actually wraps a snap-shot of the collection at the time the enumeration was requested. Maybe not appropriate for your purposes, but obviously way less prone to deadlock.

Comment: I have verified that all my enumerations are completing, which is why this is perplexing. I've decided to use an alternate solution though, so I've given up trying to figure out why!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your approach of creating your own implementation would be using the thread-safe collections built in to .NET.  I'm not sure which version of .NET you are using, but starting with .NET 4, some thread-safe collections were introduced that prevent the headache you are finding when creating your own.

The ConcurrentBag<T> collection is a thread-safe implementation of an unordered list of objects that may be suitable for your needs.

A list of these collections can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Except ConcurrentBag<T> doesn't implement ICollection<T>, and isn't really suitable as it doesn't support (some) collection-like operations. However, I did notice the SynchronizedCollection<T> class in System.Collections.Generic... strange that I didn't notice that one before! It does what I need, so I'm using that one instead. While your answer was insightful, I can't mark it as correct as I still haven't determined what the error in my original implementation is.